# FragmentTransaction can't replace fragment working with ABS

Tags: java, android

I have an activity called HomeActivity,

```
{
public class HomeActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity
}
```

but the code below here

```
{


    private void selectItem(int position) {

        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        // Locate Position
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, home);
            break;
        case 1:
            ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, gadget);
            break;
        case 2:
            ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, news);
            break;
        case 3:
            ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, techno);
            break;
        case 4:
            ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, game);
            break;
        case 5:
            ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, tips);
            break;
        case 6:
            ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, cgt);
            break;
        case 7:
            ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, info);
            break;
        }
        ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
        ft.commit();
        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        // Close drawer
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);

    }
}

FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
```

the FragmentTransaction can't replace my fragment in SherlockFragmentActivity.

I have no idea with this, I search and implements some method from google and stackoverflow but my issue still not sot
please I need a hint with this..thanks

Comment: so what's the error and logcat ?

Answer (score 0):

When working with compatibility frameworks like ActionBarSherlock and Google Support Library
it's easy to mix up imports with the native APIs.

Just take the FragmentTransaction class for example.

Make sure you are not importing the native version.

```
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
```

Instead make sure you import the version from the support library.

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
```

Actually check all your imports that you use in your project making
sure you are picking the right ones (support.v4.app).

Comment: i have imported like what you say, but it still not working :(

Comment: Then my second guess it that your problem has something to do with the layout. Is R.id.content_frame referring to a FrameLayout? Could you also try to change the "replace" method with the "add" method to see if anything happens.

Comment: i just dont know why it still not working, i've been change the "replace" with "add" and i still cant to replace my fragment view -_-

Comment: Can you add this into the beginning of your selectItem method.


    ViewGroup viewGroup = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.content_frame);
    viewGroup.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);

    if(true)
     return;

The place in the layout where the fragment(s) are supposed to be visible should now be red.